# Spring Jpa Method Having Containing or Like method only runs once

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My project structure is: Product, ProductRepository extends Jpa<Product, Long>, ProductService, ProductController
On ProductRepository:

- when I write:

```
List<Product> findByNameContaining(String name);
```

Code only run once correctly. When I resend the url request, it returns "500 internal server". On terminal, there is a bug announcement:

```
2022-05-17 13:05:25.940 ERROR 76682 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]] with root cause
```

- when I include @Query before that line, code runs normally

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.name like concat('%', :name, '%')")
List<Product> findByNameContaining(String name);
```

However, other methods like `findByName(String name)`, or Post request also works normally. I also connected to the database, other projects work well on my computer. The bug only occurs with methods: findByNameContaining, findByNameLike
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't need the `@Query`, so I wonder how are you calling this method. It looks like you are passing something that doesn't comply with what is expected.

Comment: here is link to my project: https://github.com/Puppychan/MockManufacturerWeb. I am not sure what's wrong with them

Comment: If you post with nothing (empty `String`) this will lead to an error. Also you don't want to use the `HttpEntity` etc. in your service as that ties your service to the web layer, use those only in your controller, let the service just return a result (a list of products). .

Comment: I have also posted the body before sending get request. After I let the Service layer only return a result: In the first time, get request returns an array in json format. However, on second time send, the whole array is totally null even the database still has data (I checked by sending findAll() get request).

Comment: I have just checked the terminal message when running:
- When first time send:
`Hibernate: 
    select
        product0_.id as id1_0_,
        product0_.description as descript2_0_,
        product0_.name as name3_0_ 
    from
        product product0_ 
    where
        product0_.name like ? escape ?`
However, second time send, it doesn't have Where ... ?escape?:
`Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.description as descript2_0_, product0_.name as name3_0_  from product product0_`

Comment: Please don't add additional code/logging etc. as comments as that is unreadable. Could you please show what you are sending (as an edit to your question)?

Comment: Here is how I sent the requests:
- First, Post: http://localhost:8080/api/products with json body
- Then, Get: http://localhost:8080/api/products?name=Same
Results is array of json objects that have name containing "Same"
- Then, resend Get: http://localhost:8080/api/products?name=Same
Results is nothing (or 500 Internal Server)

Comment: I also have just discovered 1 thing:
- method findByNameContaining works normal if the return type is Page<Product>
- the problem only occurs when the return type is List<Product>